# Why doesn't  my likebox doesn't show any faces?

Tags: facebook, facebook-like, privacy, facebook-social-plugins, facebook-likebox

I have a likebox generated with this code:

```
<fb:like-box href="http://www.facebook.com/pages/Browser-Games/260061187354628" width="250" show_faces="true" stream="false" header="true"></fb:like-box>
```

The SDK is loaded like this:

```
FB.init({appId: '111929132246901', status: true, cookie: true, xfbml: true});
```

(website is ibrowsergame.it if you want to see the full code)

- When I'm logged in with the page's admin account, I can see the facepile being correctly filled with photos.
- If I login with another account, there are just 2 faces.

Is this just a problem of mine, or is everyone experiencing this due to privacy settings?

It's strange that there just 2 people willing to display their profile photo (out of 180). Isn't it?

The result is pretty awful, because I have around 50px of unusued white space, if no faces are displayed.

Comment: Seems like an issue related to the accounts you're testing the like-box, I've been able to inject next code on your page (via DOM inspector)

`<fb:like-box href="http://www.facebook.com/pages/Browser-Games/260061187354628" width="250" show_faces="true" stream="false" header="true" class="  fb_iframe_widget "/>`
And then running `FB.XFBML.parse()` which resulted in rendering of like-box widget with 4 faces.

Answer (score 0):

First, are you using **facepile** (as stated in your text) or **like-box** (as stated in the code example)?

If you're using the facepile plugin, this behavior is as designed .  The plugin will only show the faces of friends who've liked the page/ or app.  If none of your friends like it, then it will be completely blank.